# Including entire project as library android studio

Tags: java, android, import, android-studio, project

I am trying to import my own library into one of my apps in Android Studio. I have seen instructions in several places that basically amount to :

**1** Move the files into a library folder within your project diectory.
**2**  Add `include 'projectName:folderName:libraryName` to your settings.gradle file
**3** Add `compile project('folderName:libraryName')` under dependencies to your project level build.gradle file

This works for me if I am importing a module... I think its a module. I'm still trying to figure out gradle. My library structure looks like this:

```
ProjectName
    Module1
        Classes
    Module2
        Classes2
```

If I import Module1 or Module2 separately in this fashion (where Module1 is my 'libraryName' in the instructions above), they will work. But if I try to import the whole project as one library I get errors.

What am I doing wrong? **I would like to import the entire project** as I would like it to have many modules. Is there another/better way to do this? What am I misunderstanding?

**Update:**
As per @ScottBarta 's instructions I merged settings.gradle files. **This appears to have worked in my main project** because the gradle sync completed properly but I'm not ready to run that project. **So I made a tester project** and imported the library using the same steps. **This time I get the error:**

```
Gradle 'Tester' project refresh failed:
Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found. 'compile()'!
```

As near as I can tell, the files are equivalent in the two projects:

Main:

```
include ':Eed'
include ':Eed:libraries:Overt:Visible'
include ':Eed:libraries:Overt:Control'
```

Test:

```
include ':app'
include ':app:libraries:Overt:Visible'
include ':app:libraries:Overt:Control'
```

Main:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project('libraries:Overt:Visible')
    compile project('libraries:Overt:Control')
}
```

Test

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    complie project('libraries:Overt:Visible')
    complie project('libraries:Overt:Control')

}
```

And here's a [screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/29c87t0/8) of the file structure in the Tester project.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one **settings.gradle** file per project, so if you have a multi-module library with its own **settings.gradle**, you can't bring it in with a single `include` statement. You'll need to merge the library's **settings.gradle** into that of the project you're including it in.

When you do the merge, make sure that all the `include` statements in the merged **settings.gradle** have sensible paths that will locate their libraries relative to the project root. Also keep in mind that the paths specified in your **settings.gradle** file have to match what's in your `dependencies` block. So if you have this:

```
include ':app'
include ':app:libraries:Overt:Visible'
include ':app:libraries:Overt:Control'
```

You need this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':app:libraries:Overt:Visible')
    compile project(':app:libraries:Overt:Control')
}
```

In the build script you posted in your question, there's a typo: it says `complie` instead of `compile`. If that's a typo in your build script and not just a typo in your question here, that will be a problem.

Comment: Is that as simple as copy pasting them together?

Comment: You'll have to get the paths to each module correct, but yes, you pretty much just mash them together. Give it a shot, and if you run into problems you can't figure out, add more details to your question.

Comment: I think you've solved my problem but I'm getting weird results. Updated the question.

Comment: Yep that typo was a problem. I'm sitting to far from the monitor to see the l vs i thing. Final question, why does the main project *seem* to run fine with `compile project('libraries:Overt:Control')` instead of `compile project('**:app:**libraries:Overt:Control')`?

Comment: Actually, I didn't think carefully about it. Your original statements `compile project('libraries:...')` would work fine. The leading colon in the spec acts like a leading delimiter in an OS path: it makes the path absolute instead of relative. You had set it up as a path relative to the "app" module root, which was okay. In my correction, I set it up as a path absolute to the project root, which is also okay. I often see problems where users have mismatches that don't work, so I reflexively suggested you correct it here.

Comment: Did not know that. Obviously I need a crash course in gradle. :)

Comment: This has worked wonderfully but when I try to import the project now that its modules are interdependent I get an error. I made a new module dependent on another and now It won't import properly. I posted a full question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399719/android-studio-library-project-dependencies) but I can't get any help.